# Magento 2 - Is it bad practice to directly use SQL in php?

Tags: database, model, sql

We are using a third party module. They have their own database tables and read out data from it by using direct SQL statements

**app/code/Company/Foo/Model/Calculator.php**

...

```
public function foo($fugenMoertel) {

    $fugenMoertelTable = $this->_resource->getTableName( 'px_fugenmasse' );
    $binds = array(
        'moertel' => $fugenMoertel
    );

    /* with sku's */
    $query = "SELECT gewicht, gebindegroesse, packung FROM " . $fugenMoertelTable . " where artikelnummer = :moertel";


    $result = $this->connection->query( $query, $binds );
    while ( $row = $result->fetch() ) {
        $moertel['gewicht'] = $row['gewicht'];
        $moertel['groesse'] = $row['gebindegroesse'];
        $moertel['packung'] = $row['packung'];
    }     
    return $moertel;
}
```

Is this considered as bad practice? If yes, does it give any disadvantage? Why should you avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.

Magento code base is also writing direct SQL in PHP classes. For example https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Category.php#L557

However, **be careful** when writing direct SQL queries to avoid SQL injection attacks.

The code in the 3rd-party module you mentioned is safe as they use [PDO::prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) to prepare the SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure all the inputs are sanitized and always use the tableName function to the table name

```
$table = $this->resourceConnection->getTableName('sales_order_item');
```

Comment: Why do I need `getTableName` if I know the table name already?

Comment: Its best practices use the getTableName when we have tablename with prefix in database.